# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType ...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I am working on an **ASP.net core** project using `Identity`.

**What I try to do:**

I try to let the web App create new default **user** and **roles**

Everything was fine, until I added and called a method inside `ConfigureServices` in `Startup` class

**after that I got this error/exception**

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.IViewCompilerProvider Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompilerProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompilerProvider'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CSharpCompiler Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CSharpCompiler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager'.)'
```

**ConfigureServices method:**

```
public async Task ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser, IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    //This is the method I try to call
     await CreateDefaultRoles(serviceProvider);
}
```

**Method I try to call :**

```
  public async Task CreateDefaultRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var userManager      = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            var roleManager      = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            bool isAdminRoleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");

            if (!isAdminRoleExist)
            {
                var roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Admin.ToString()));
            }

            var defaultAdminUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");

            if (defaultAdminUser == null)
            {
                AppUser defaultAdmin = new AppUser()
                                       {
                                           UserName = "Admin",
                                           Email    = "my@email.com"
                                       };
                var defaultAdminTask = await userManager.CreateAsync(defaultAdmin, "MYP@ssword2021");

                if (defaultAdminTask.Succeeded)
                {
                    var adminToRoleTask = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultAdmin, Roles.Admin.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

**So please any help about this problem ??**

Comment: As far as I understand ConfigureServices, it is not a place where you call other methods to create default data. It should be used for registering services and setting configuration options by convention. Whether the error is due to this I don't know.

Comment: what .net core version are you using? I've just spotted a new feature which supports injecting more services into the `ConfigureServices` :) - because as what I've experienced with `.net core 2.2`, that's impossible, only one `IServiceCollection` is injected into there. For your error, it's easy to understand, at the time building the DI container, your Identity's services like `UserManager`, `RoleManager` ... have not been available yet. The container has not been even built, so the `IServiceProvider` you get is just another hidden instance provided by the framework.

Comment: move the migration code to a later phase, such as when configuring the application builder inside `Startup.Configure`.

Comment: I use .Net 5 this project based on Asp.net core 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to move the seeding to `Configure()`, because in `ConfigureServices()` the `ServiceProvider` is not built yet, since you're just configuring it.

You could call `services.BuildServiceProvider()`, but this is problematic, and there is no need to do that, because you can implement seeding quite nicely in `Configure()`.

The main thing is to do the whole seeding in a new scope, and then dispose it.

This is a solid approach for example:

```cs
public async Task Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    await CreateDefaultRoles(app);
    ...
}

public async Task CreateDefaultRoles(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
{
    using (var scope = appBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;

        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        // Do your seeding stuff
    }
}
```

I can only assume that `Configure()` work as an `async` method; never tried to use it that way. I simply seed the database with sync methods.

Let me know if this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: This solution is work, but the `Configure` method should be stay void cause `host builder` throw an exception if `Configure` changed to `Task`, massive thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error and my problem was I forgot to set the type for `ILogger`. My original code was:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
```

Fixed by setting `ILogger<MyClass>` (fixed in private field and in constructor):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
```